# discord py how to give returning members their old roles back

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want to reassign roles when a user from my discord server left and come a few days later back.

The Carl.gg bot does have this feature, it's called "reassign roles", but I want to code it self. How is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to keep some type of database of all of the users' discord ids and their corresponding roles. Then when someone joins your server you would need to check if their id is in your database and based on that give them their corresponding role.

Comment: You can google how to make & use databases in python, there's plenty of posts & tutorials on how to do that.